# send sms with help of paytm for invoice gives error

Tags: php, codeigniter, paytm

I want to send sms with help of paytm for invoice

I have below code with my codeigniter

in third_party folder I have library of paytm and I have called stagging api like below,

```
 $this->load->library('paytm');
        $paytm = $this->paytm->load();
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["mid"] = "mystaggingmid";
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["recipientName"] = 'hetal';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["recipientNumber"] = 'mycontactno';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["phoneType"] = "smart";
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["invoiceId"] = '1234';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["expiryDate"] = '20/3/2018';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["taxType"] = "inclusive";
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["discountType"] = 'beforetax';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["discountMode"] = 'percentage';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["discountValue"] = "2";
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["invoiceAmt"] = '10';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["tax"] = 'SALES';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["description"] = '';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["callbackUrl"] = 'mysiteurl';
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["checksumhash"] = $paytm->getChecksumFromArray($paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY); //Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
        $responseParamList = $paytm->callAPI("https://pguat.paytm.com/PayTMSecured/app/restapi/sendsms", $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA);

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($responseParamList);
        die("test to die");
```

this code gives me error like below,

```
array(2) {
  ["errorCode"]=>
  string(9) "SMSINV-17"
  ["errorMsg"]=>
  string(18) "Json Parsing error"
}
test to die
```

Comment: Before passing as argument. try to debug this array -- $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA . var_dump

Comment: your SMS content is wrong, verify the JSON after encoding it.

Comment: I have ckeck my array for parameters and update as below but not worked: $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["MID"] = "mystaggingmid";
        $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"]="myindustrytype";
         $paytm->PAYTM_POST_DATA["WEBSITE"]="mywebsite";